# MVC 3 - Validation for "isDateTime" not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, datetime-format

I got 2 DateTime field and i use datepicker for user to choose a date. However, since it is a textbox, user can still enter any value and click the submit button. So, I wish to have validation on the DateTime textfield to check whether the value submitted is a DateTime with specific format. I tried this:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Storage Date is required")]
[DataType(DataType.DateTime, ErrorMessage = "Please input a valid date")]
public DateTime StorageDate { get; set; }
```

However, I dint get any message even i input "xxxxx" in the textbox and submit (Note: the [Required] validation do work)

My form is like this:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    Storage Date
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBox("StorageDate", String.Format("{0:ddd, d MMM yyyy}", DateTime.Now), new { id = "storagedate" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StorageDate)
</div>
```

So, I need check the Date according to the format also.. Any idea why it is not working???

Any help is really appreciated...Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a regular expression annotation to the property of your view model:

```
[RegularExpression("Expression_goes_here", "Date is of invalid format.")]
```

[Here is a link for a REGEX library - you may choose to use one of their expressions for validating date.](http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=4&categoryId=5&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

Comment: hi, Thanks! a simple solution, i am doing like this:
[RegularExpression(@"^(((((((0?[13578])|(1[02]))[\.\-/]?((0?[1-9])|([12]\d)|(3[01])))|(((0?[469])|(11))[\.\-/]?((0?[1-9])|([12]\d)|(30)))|((0?2)[\.\-/]?((0?[1-9])|(1\d)|(2[0-8]))))[\.\-/]?(((19)|(20))?([\d][\d]))))|((0?2)[\.\-/]?(29)[\.\-/]?(((19)|(20))?(([02468][048])|([13579][26])))))$", ErrorMessage = "Please input a valid date")] 
Is it correct?

Comment: If your REGEX is correct, then yes - this will work. If you have more view models with a DateTime type property, then I would suggest using counsellorben's solution as it promotes re-usability.

Comment: Hi, I cant find any regex which validate date in the format of Mon, 31 Oct 2011 (datepicker format: 'D, dd M yy'). Any idea?? Or i can actually disable the text field so to ensure user only choose date from the datepicker?

Answer (score 1):

In order to validate that the value in the textbox is a valid date, you need to add a `RegularExpressionAttribute` with a regex for a date format.  I use a custom attribute, with a regex to validate that a string is in the format mm/dd/yyyy.

```
public class DateAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    public DateAttribute()
    {
        ErrorMessage = "{0} is not a valid date";
    }

    private string _pattern = "^(((0?[1-9]|1[012])/(0?[1-9]|1\\d|2[0-8])|(0?[13456789]|1[012])/(29|30)|(0?[13578]|1[02])/31)/(19|[2-9]\\d)\\d{2}|0?2/29/((19|[2-9]\\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(([2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))$";

    private string _fieldLabel;
    public string FieldLabel
    {
        get { return _fieldLabel; }
        set { _fieldLabel = value; }
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return String.Format(ErrorMessageString, name);
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(_fieldLabel),
            ValidationType = "regex",
        };
        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("pattern", _pattern);
        yield return rule;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))
            return null;
        Regex regex = new Regex(_pattern);
        if (regex.IsMatch(value.ToString()))
            return null;

        return new ValidationResult(
            FormatErrorMessage(_fieldLabel)
        );
    }
}
```

Decorate the property with [Date], and you're set.

Comment: Hi, I tried this method before, but i get compilation error at IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule>

Comment: Do you have `using System.Web.Mvc;` in your class file?